# Use both envers RevisionRepository and JpaRepository in the same application

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I want to have a repository for entities (regular JPA repository) as well as a separate repository that keeps track of audit information (a RevisionRepository, part of hibernate envers).

I cannot seem to get this to work in my application.

As far as I can understand, each type of repository needs to be instantiated with it's own factory (JpaRepository with `repositoryFactoryBeanClass`, and `RevisionRepository` with `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean`), and that can be set with the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

The issue is that only one of that annotation can be on my main class. I have seen an example of this being done in xml form ([here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-sandbox/tree/2c02b575d21b3b257f3f6dbf7d0bb8426dd6db8d/jpa-revision/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/example/spring/config)), but I don't know how to do this with annotations.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` extends the `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` so you should only have to specify the `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` in your configuration to get both to work for you.

What happens internally is that if the `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` determines that your repository does not implement the the correct interface, it will delegate to the super implementation, which in this case is the `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean`.

Comment: This is the error I get when I try that:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [...repositories.MyRevisionRepository] found for dependency [...repositories.MyRevisionRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Can you post your interface for `MyRevisionRepository` ?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you need to create two separate configuration classes for `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` and `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` as show in following code.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.jpa.dao")
class JpaConfig {}

@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean, basePackages = "com.example.envers.dao")
class EnversConfig {}
```

It works for me. But could not get why `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` works only for `RevisionRepository` and not `JPRepository` though `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean`.

Some one please edit answer and provide explanation so it will be helpful for others as well.